# Lambda constexpr works in msvc but not in gcc

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I wrote the following program that compiles with msvc but not with gcc and clang.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xhes5fvoc)

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto func = []()constexpr { return 1; };
    auto i = []{return func();};
}
```

I want to know which compiler is right here?

GCC says:

```
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:3:28: error: 'func' is not captured
    3 |     auto i = []{return func();};
      |                        ~~~~^~
<source>:3:15: note: the lambda has no capture-default
    3 |     auto i = []{return func();};
      |               ^
<source>:2:20: note: 'constexpr const main()::<lambda()> func' declared here
    2 |     constexpr auto func = []()constexpr { return 1; };
      |
```

Answer (score 6):

MSVC seems to be right here.

From [lambda expression's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> **captures**  -   A comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with a capture-default.
>
> **A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing it if the variable**
>
> - has const non-volatile integral or enumeration type and has been initialized with a constant expression, or
> - **is constexpr and has no mutable members**.

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is an invocation of a non-static member function (the function call operator, `operator()`) on `func`, equivalent to `func.operator()()`.

This constitutes an *odr-use* of `func` ([[basic.def.odr]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-use)):

> A variable `x` that is named by a potentially-evaluated expression *E* is *odr-used* by *E* unless
>
> - `x` is a reference that is usable in constant expressions, or
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and *E* is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied, or
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type, and *E* is an element of the set of potential results of a discarded-value expression to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied.

...in a scope where it is not *odr-usable* ([[basic.def.odr]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-usable)):

> A local entity is *odr-usable* in a scope if:
>
> - either the local entity is not `*this`, or an enclosing class or non-lambda function parameter scope exists and, if the innermost such scope is a function parameter scope, it corresponds to a non-static member function, and
> - for each intervening scope between the point at which the entity is introduced and the scope (where `*this` is considered to be introduced within the innermost enclosing class or non-lambda function definition scope), either:
>
>   - the intervening scope is a block scope, or
>   - the intervening scope is the function parameter scope of a *lambda-expression* that has a *simple-capture* naming the entity or has a *capture-default*, and the block scope of the *lambda-expression* is also an intervening scope.

...which means the program is ill-formed ([[basic.def.odr]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10.sentence-2)):

> If a local entity is odr-used in a scope in which it is not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: You should highlight in **bold** which specific part is applicable here instead of copy/pasting the whole paragraph. I mean, right now it is not clear which bullet applies here. Highlight the bullet point in **bolt** that is applicable to make it clear.